# Prove linear dependency in $\mathbb{F}_{m}[z]$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

> Let $\mathbb{F}_{m}[z]$ denote the vector space of all polynomials with degree less than or equal to $m\in\mathbb{Z}_{+}$ and having coefficients over $\mathbb{F}$, and suppose that $p_{0},p_{1},\ldots,p_{m}\in\mathbb{F}_{m}[z]$ satisfy $p_{j}(2)=0$. Prove that $(p_{0},p_{1},\ldots,p_{m})$ is a linearly dependent list of vectors in $\mathbb{F}_{m}[z]$.

Could someone verify my solution?

If we let $p_{0}=0$, then
\begin{align*}
2p_{0}+0p_{1}+0p_{2}+\cdots+0p_{m}=0
\end{align*}
where $p_{j}$ for $j=1,2,\ldots,m$ is any polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_{m}[z]$ of degree $j$. Hence $(p_{0},p_{1},\ldots,p_{m})$ is linear independent in $\mathbb{F}_{m}[z]$.

Comment: and if we don't have $p_0=0$?

Comment: But we always have $0\in\mathbb{F}_{m}[z]$. So it's just a matter of giving it, an index?

Comment: The question asks to show that *any* list of vectors $(p_0,\ldots,p_m)$ with $p_j(2)=0$ is linearly dependent, not to show that there exists such a linearly independent list; this is obvious.

Comment: No. You know that $0 \in F_m[z]$, and that $0$ is a polynomial satisfying your relation, but this doesn't mean that it must be one of the $p_j$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** Let $W= \{ f \in \mathbb{F}_{m}[z] |f(2)=0 \}$. Prove that $W$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{F}_{m}[z]$. As $\dim_{F} \mathbb{F}_{m}[z] =m+1$, and $W \neq \mathbb{F}_{m}[z]$, what can you say about the dimmension of $W$?

Comment: Im not sure I follow you.

Comment: I am able to prove that $W$ is a subspace, but I can't figure out what the dimension has to do with linear independence.

Answer (score 2):

On the same tone as the other answer: prove that

$$\phi_2: \Bbb F_m[x]\to\Bbb F\;\;,\;\;\phi_2(f):=f(2)$$

is a homomorphism of vector spaces (i.e., a linear functional) and precisely $\;W=\ker\phi_2\;$.

Now use the dimensions theorem, for example...